# Why common ancestor required in 3-way merge required in git?

Tags: git

I am new to git , i understand what is fast-forward merge [If two branch are linear just move the pointer to branch] but when it come to 3-way merge its bit confusing for me because why 3-way merge require common ancestor to create a new commit why cannot take the two branch[The branch which i want to merge to(eg:master) and some branch which want to merge(eg: immediatefix)] and compare them and just do a merge .. why do you want common ancestor.And also in rebase why we need common ancestor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s rather simple and boils down to how Git stores commits. Unlike other VCS, Git stores full snapshots of the whole working directory. As such, when looking at a single commit, all you can see is the exact state of what’s inside that commit.

Other VCS like Subversion usually store diffs. So a revision is stored as a difference between the previous state and the current state. So when merging you just have to look at a single revision to see *what happened* and you can apply that somewhere else.

Git on the other hand does not have that difference readily available. To be able to see what happened in a commit, it needs to compare the contents with the parent commit. Only then it can generate a difference and apply that somewhere else. So for two branches `A` and `B` with a common base `C`, what Git does is look at the difference between `A` and `C`, and `B` and `C`. Then it knows what exactly happened in each branch and can try to apply all changes. This further has the benefit that the *whole* range of changes is being looked at, so if you temporarily changed something in one branch but undid that later, it won’t appear for the full difference when merging. This usually leads to fewer conflicts.

The same applies to rebases too, except that it’s actually in the name of it. When rebasing `B` onto `A`, you are basically rewriting all the commits from the range `C..B` to have `A` as the parent instead. So Git will look at the difference between `C` and the first commit on the branch and apply that to `A`. Then it will look at the difference between the first commit and the second commit and apply that. And that goes on until the whole branch was *rebased* to have `A` as its *base*.

---

> That's where i get confused if A has full snapshot and B has its full snapshot we can compare A and B and we can merge it so why we need common base C?

Well, let’s try an example for this. We’ll just look at a single file to make it easier, but this would happen for every file in the repository.

Suppose this is the file’s content in branch A:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
```

And this is the content in branch B:

```
alpha
gamma
delta
```

Now what would the merged version be like? If you don’t know what the commits actually *changed* you cannot safely decide that. For example we could say, that the file originally (in C) had only `alpha` and `gamma`. So in the branch A `beta` was added, and in B `delta` was added. This would result in this:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```

Or we could assume the inverse, saying the file originally had all four lines in, so in A `delta` was removed and in B `beta` was removed:

```
alpha
gamma
```

Or we could could say that branch B actually *never touched* the file, so its state should be ignored and A’s content should be kept. The same could apply in reverse if branch A never touched the file.

As you can see, having the base of those branches, and as such the actual difference for the branches helps a lot in deciding how a merge should be resolved. After all, we want to use branches to develop stuff independently from other branches (with other independent development lines) and just merge all our changes in without having to do all the work during merge again.

Comment: .That's where i get confused if A has full snapshot and B has its full snapshot we can compare A and B and we can merge it so why we need common base C

Comment: @vicky I expanded my answer with an example, hope that makes it clear :)

Comment: I think i got it.Taking a common ancestor file checking with the other two file, if any changes found in one file use that change if both changed make it conflict  .   Am i right ?

Comment: Git is actually a bit smarter and will decide on a per-line basis. So if you add code in different parts of the file (e.g. each branch adds a method to a class), you won’t get a conflict but Git will automatically make sure both are there in the merged version :)